# Instagram API Real Time geography subscriptions - too few requests

Tags: api, instagram, subscription, geography

I've implemented the real time functionality on the Instagram API by subscribing to 5 geographies.
These geographies pretty much cover the area of Bucharest, so I'm thinking I should get a lot of action from Instagram's servers.

Here's the way I implemented everything in PHP (CodeIgniter):

- I created a callback page for all 5 geographies which analyses the raw post from the Instagram API, gets the geography ID and then requests the recent photos uploaded from that area to [the geography endpoint](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/geographies/) based on the respective geography ID
- I parse this response and I cache the photos' data so I can retrieve it later
- I show the last 30 results on http://hipstagram.ro/

The problem is that I've made a few tests by taking photos with my phone from one of these areas and sometimes my photo shows up, and sometimes it doesn't. The implementation isn't throwing any errors, but it works strangely. Thus... I have a couple of unanswered questions:

Q: Could I be missing requests? It says in the [Instagram API docs](http://instagram.com/developer/realtime/#receiving-updates) that I should acknowledge the request in less than 2 seconds. Here's how my code looks like in the callback method (PHP CodeIgniter):

```
if ($_SERVER ['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    header("Content-Length: 0");
    header("Connection: close");
    flush();

    // do stuff with file_get_contents('php://input')
    // also, get new photos...

    $data   = json_decode (file_get_contents('php://input'));

    if (is_array ($data))
        foreach ($data as $geo) {
            $this->db->query ("LOGGING SOMETHING HERE...");

            // make some a cURL request to the geography endpoint
            // get the photos, save them in the database
            $this->live->updateGeo ($geo->object_id);
        }
}
```

Q: If I'm missing requests:

- is it because the callback takes too long due to the added time of `$this->live->updateGeo` (which waits for the cURL call to end)?
- is it because my server is in Romania and all the requests from Instagram come from USA IPs?

I've analysed the raw access logs and from time to time I get a spike of requests, then a long span of silence. I'm thinking it's either because the Instagram API is not posting anything to me or because I'm not responding in less than 2 seconds. Otherwise... why are those requests taking place all at once (5-10 requests in a couple of seconds)? It's not like 5-10 people just happen to take photos all at the same time and then everybody just puts their phone back in the pocket :)